# Jmeter BackendListener: How to use runtime variables

Tags: jmeter

Trying to use BackendListener and observed runtime variables are not written to influxDB.

Predefined variables and properties, on the other hand, can be written to influx.

So I can separate test results by some ID by setting measurement=${__P(SOME_ID)}

What I'm looking for is a splitting results by thread group name, as I may have up to several dozens of them within the same test.

Tried to use following:

- TAG_scenarioName=${__threadGroupName}
- TAG_someJmeterVar=${SOME_JMETER_VAR}
- TAG_someJmeterVarAsGroovy=${__groovy(vars.get("SOME_JMETER_VAR"),)}
- eventTags=${__threadGroupName} testTitle=${__threadGroupName} (this
- one makes less sense, but still..)

and none of those works

Those are works:
 - TAG_injectorName=${__machineName()}
 - TAG_predefinedVar=${USER_DEFINED_VAR} (I believe this is thanks to [this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57962))

So as I understand problem is with runtime variables only. Is it possible to make runtime variables accessible for the BackendListener? Or maybe there is some workaround for such case?

p.s. opened an [enh](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63478) for this

Answer (score 0):

Based on your inputs. Please try with "[sample variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)"
These are defined in user.properties like:-

```
sample_variables=FileName,retHREF,PageID,Redirect,StatusCode
```

So, put all your variables in the sample_variables, restart jmeter and try. Please check if this helps.

Comment: I don't need write vars to a file. I'm looking making BackendListener writing runtime data to InfluxDB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of JMeter 5.1.1 (last version at time of this answer).

It's a feature request which is not implemented yet:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57962